# Link to application insights search by URL parameter

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

is it possible to start application insights search by URL parameter?

see the picture below: I like to generate a link to start the search:

[image]

something like: `https://<applicatoinInsightsUrl>?search=b4eb0000-f22e-18db-fc92-08d81c2df34d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot.

Actually, when you use `search` from portal, it calls the `application insights get query rest api` in the backend. And it also auto-generates a token for the authentication(if you already logged in azure portal).

So just a simple url plus search="xxx" will do nothing. You can consider using [get query api](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/query).

Comment: thanks! i am giving the query api a try. if i find a solution i will post it here.

Comment: If the answer helps, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks. By the way, as I mentioned, it's not possible without the query api:).

Comment: you are right. If it is not possible by Url param, you answered the question. Thanks man!